# handling different scopes and versions in Pipe through Phoenix Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have 2 pipelines in my `router.ex`

```
  pipeline :api_v1 do
    plug :accepts, ["json", "jpg"]
    plug CORSPlug, origin: ["*"]
    plug APIVersion, version: :v1
  end

  pipeline :api_v2 do
    plug :accepts, ["json", "jpg"]
    plug CORSPlug, origin: ["*"]
    plug APIVersion, version: :v2
  end
```

and then I have these 2 scopes.

One for `/v2`

```
  scope "/v2", EvercamMediaWeb do
    pipe_through :api_v2
```

One for `/v1`

```
  scope "/v1", EvercamMediaWeb do
    pipe_through :api_v1
```

in both scopes, all the routes are the same. and as of having 2 pipelines and 2 versions, I have to duplicate all routes in 2 different pipe_through, Is that possible to make this dynamic?

So that all the routes will be written once in `router.ex` file but both scopes can be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s still plain old good *Elixir*, the basic syntax applies.

```rb
for v <- [:v1, :v2] do
  pipeline :"api_#{v}" do
    plug :accepts, ["json", "jpg"]
    plug CORSPlug, origin: ["*"]
    plug APIVersion, version: v
  end
end
```

and the same for scopes

```rb
for v <- [:v1, :v2] do
  scope to_string(v), EvercamMediaWeb do
    pipe_through :"api_#{v}"
end
```

Comment: how to replace it here ? ` plug APIVersion, version: :v1`

Comment: Oups, sorry, did not realize it happens to appear twice there. Updated. It’s plain _Elixir_ code.

Comment: I do not follow, sorry.

Comment: I mean instead of a for a loop this be done in a Plug  which then just will be used in router.ex?

Comment: There are two different pipelines, I do not see how modifications in the pipeline link might be of any help here.